# Firebase database table call multiple time

Tags: php, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am calling firebase data using PHP  (third party Library https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php)  when I call the Firebase table using only PHP  it call single time, but when I add a javascript tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    // Code 
});
```

firebase table calls 2 times

Here is my firebase database call history [image]

Don't know its going on